# Python import ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'

Tags: python, import

I have problem with this [hmm](https://github.com/jamesmcinerney/np-hmm/tree/master/model) code that I have cloned

When I go for

```
python testing/example.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing/example.py", line 2, in <module>
    from model import sensors, general_inf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'
```

Why is import not working?
I could change the original code but I do not understand the error.Three lines from example.py

```
from model import sensors, general_inf
from testing import viz, synth
from numpy import shape
```

Comment: Where do you have your testing/example.py ? You can't expect python to figure out the modules by searching your PC you know.

Comment: Yeah,I copied model to testing.

Comment: Give us something more to help you out like your dir structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the code on my computer, after **moving the file `example.py` out of the `testing` directory**, it worked(as the picture shows).
 [image]
Besides, I think if you add the absolute path of `model` into `sys.path`, it **may** work as well.(not tested)